# error when executing a dynamic sql string

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I am getting an error when attempting to execue a dynamic sql string in MS Access (I am using VBA to write the code).

Error:

> Run-time error '3075':
>   Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression "11/8/2013' FROM tbl_sample'.

Here is my code:

```
Sub UpdateAsOfDate()

    Dim AsOfDate As String
    AsOfDate = Form_DateForm.txt_AsOfDate.Value
    AsOfDate = Format(CDate(AsOfDate))

    Dim dbs As Database

    Set dbs = OpenDatabase("C:\database.mdb")

            Dim strSQL As String
            strSQL = " UPDATE tbl_sample " _
                    & "SET tbl_sample.As_of_Date = '" _
                    & AsOfDate _
                    & "' " _
                    & "FROM tbl_sample " _
                    & "WHERE tbl_sample.As_of_Date IS NULL ;"


        dbs.Execute strSQL

    dbs.Close 
End Sub
```

I piped the strSQL to a MsgBox so I could see the finished SQL string, and it looks like it would run without error. What's going on?

Comment: IIRC, Access likes to have it's date literals quoted with "#" instead of apostrophes.  Like ` ... = #11/8/2013#`.

Comment: `"FROM ` is not valid in `UPDATE`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get rid of `& "FROM tbl_sample " _`.  A from clause isn't valid in your update statement.

Answer (score 2):

Include the `#` date delimiters into your *AsOfDate* string.

```vb
AsOfDate = Format(Form_DateForm.txt_AsOfDate.value, "\#yyyy-m-d\#")
```

Then use that pre-formatted *AsOfDate* string when you build the `UPDATE` statement.

```
strSQL = "UPDATE tbl_sample AS t" & vbCrLf & _
    "SET t.As_of_Date = " & AsOfDate & vbCrLf & _
    "WHERE t.As_of_Date IS NULL;"
```

Also notice I discarded the `FROM` clause because it's not valid in an Access `UPDATE`, as the others have mentioned.

Or you could convert to a parameter query, and avoid dealing with the date delimiters.

Answer (score 2):

You really should be using a parameterized query because

- they're safer,
- you don't have to mess with delimiters for date and text values,
- you don't have to worry about escaping quotes within text values, and
- they handle dates properly so your code doesn't mangle dates on machines set to `dd-mm-yyyy` format.

In your case you would use something like this:

```vbs
Sub UpdateAsOfDate()
    Dim db As DAO.Database, qdf As DAO.QueryDef
    Dim AsOfDate As Date

    AsOfDate = DateSerial(1991, 1, 1)  ' test data

    Set db = OpenDatabase("C:\Users\Public\Database1.accdb")
    Set qdf = db.CreateQueryDef("", _
            "PARAMETERS paramAsOfDate DateTime; " & _
            "UPDATE tbl_sample SET As_of_Date = [paramAsOfDate] " & _
            "WHERE As_of_Date IS NULL")
    qdf!paramAsOfDate = AsOfDate
    qdf.Execute
    Set qdf = Nothing
    db.Close
    Set db = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

try:-

```
    strSQL = " UPDATE t " _
            & "SET t.As_of_Date = '" _
            & AsOfDate _
            & "' " _
            & "FROM tbl_sample t " _
            & "WHERE t.As_of_Date IS NULL ;"
```

The problem may be that your Access driver is misunderstanding the alias you are using (because it exactly matches a table name).

Comment: Unfortunately, as others have pointed out, Access doesn't appear to allow this syntax for the `update` statement.  Today, as usual, I learned something...